# Retag or Synonym Script(s)(ing)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I'm not sure how all the retag or synonyms work, so if I'm barking up the wrong tree, could someone explain the difference between the two?

I noticed that there is a tag for [scripts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scripts) which has 26 Qs, [script](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/script) which has 236 Qs, and [scripting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scripting) which has 436 Qs. I'm not sure if there is a difference in the *nix house for those, but on Windows, they are all pretty much the same.

Comment: If you aren't sure how tags should be cleaned up, it's ok to just say "tags `abc`, `def`, and `xyz need to be cleaned up". We'll figure it out.

Comment: @Chris No Synonymizer cookie?

Comment: those are impossible to get the way the system is setup now. I can't even propose new synonyms. They system is broke. They've known it for a while. They haven't fixed. I have no faith it will be fixed anytime soon. Sorry if that sounds cynical, but wander over to mSO sometime and you'll end up the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent point -- merged and set up synonyms, all into the dominant [scripting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scripting).

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 3):

Nice find! That does indeed sound like a trio of tags to *merge*. When a mod merges, we have the option to make a synonym of the old tag. Looks like [scripting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/scripting) has won the vote, so the other two will still be around for those who really want them.

Or Jeff can do it first.